# Does the ReFS filesystem reserve space for itself?

Tags: filesystems, partition, windows-10, disk-space-utilization, refs

I recently formatted a single disk from the line of new 14TB Seagates on Windows 10 with ReFS, with a 4K block size, to use the full capacity available and noticed that out of the approximately 12.7TB it presents as usable that it already reports that 100GB has been consumed though the disk is empty.

I checked in disk manager and saw no additional partitions added (plus this would be space consumed within the same partition) and checked for hidden files, but turned up nothing. 100GB consumed for an empty disk seems a little surprising unless it is used for some kind of parity, but also I'm fairly new to using ReFS and don't know all its features.

I've noticed from [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview) that ReFS offers something called "**mirror-accelerated parity**", but I am not using ReFS across two or more disks, but rather a standalone disk. Could the 100GB be reserved for parity or some other feature for preventing data corruption (also mentioned in the Microsoft documentation)? And would it matter if I chose an 8K block size instead?

Any thoughts on what could be using that space?

I am asking this from a security standpoint because I am concerned that to an auditor I wouldn't be able to explain the space usage on a freshly formatted system if there were suspicion of steganography or other forms of hidden data resulting from various methods of hiding malicious software that might actually be occupying space on a drive while not being visible - in environments where monitoring of such things is very strict.

**Addendum:**

Here is some additional information I pulled about the drive from System Info:

```
Bytes/Sector: 512
Partitions: 1
Sectors/Track: 63
Tracks/Cylinder: 255
(Total Disk) Size: 12.73TB (14,000,512,296,960)
Total Cylinders: 1,702,132
Total Sectors: 27,344,750,580
Partition: Disk #0,Partition #0
Partition Size: 12.73TB (14,000,383,328,256)
Partition Starting Offset: 135,266,304 bytes
```

There is a delta in size between the **Total Disk Size** and the **Partition Size** of 122.99GB, but this does not match the now 101GB (seems like it grew by 1GB since I last looked at it - though the disk is still empty) that is reported used. And again, the 101GB is reported as consumed within the partition itself.

The disk is still empty, though I did test creation of a .txt file and then delete it. If there is parity I wonder if creation of that file is what increased the utilization reported (after the fact), even though the file was deleted.

Additional reading on ReFS:
- https://www.iperiusbackup.net/en/refs-vs-ntfs-differences-and-performance-comparison-when-to-use/

Comment: The one time I used ReFS as on a large scale it took 5.34 TB out of 1 PB just for itself. So my (not very diverse) experience is: yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me some reference point. I'm wondering why that would apply to standalone disks too though. If it is parity (though technically a disk can't parity itself - can it? Or at least it would be pointless...) I guess ReFS makes it non-optional, regardless of number of disks.

Comment: I have never used ReFS. However, BTRFS and ZFS do this same kind of stuff.. Both of those systems need reserved space for metadata, which it absolutely should report as "consumed". It's completely reasonable for a checksumming filesystem with an integrated volume manager and copy on write (COW) to consume this much space for its internals.

Comment: Metadata could be the explanation. Oddly though I've never noticed whether NTFS does this too or not. I almost formatted the drive NTFS but wanted to try ReFS.

Answer (score 1):

12.73TB (14,000,512,296,960)... Microsoft is reporting 12.7Tib, Seagate sells 14TB drives,  this is the same thing in different units.  14x10^12 = 12.73x2^40

Answer (score 0):

Yes ReFS does reserve space, and you can check this using the `fsutil` tool on Windows. The command is `fsutil fsinfo refsinfo D:`, where `D:` is your drive letter.

For my 3.6TB drive, which is a standalone drive by the way, having been initialized with a single partition spanning the whole disk using `diskpart`, and is not part of any Storage Space, `fsutil` reports this:

```
REFS Volume Serial Number :                0xde1a28bb1a289297
REFS Version   :                           3.4
Number Sectors :                           0x00000001d1c00000
Total Clusters :                           0x000000003a380000
Total Reserved :                           0x00000000003be2e8
Bytes Per Sector  :                        512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :                4096
Bytes Per Cluster :                        4096
Fast Tier Data Fill Percentage :           0.0%
Slow Tier Data Fill Percentage :           0.0%
Fast Tier to Slow Tier Rate (Clusters/s) : 0
Checksum Type :                            CHECKSUM_TYPE_NONE
```

According to the above, if we assume `Total Reserved` is a proportion of `Total Clusters`, then about 0.4% of free space is reserved. It's a bit weird though as after I had just finished formatting it, Windows Explorer reported that at least 36GB of space was already occupied, which amounts to about 1% of reserved space, not 0.4%.

Also running the command on other volumes formatted with ReFS, sometimes I see the reserved space proportion varies. Once it was 0.7%.

I couldn't find any official Microsoft documentation on how to interpret the hexadecimal numbers that `fsutil` reports, so maybe my caclulation is wrong.